# Gradients throw cells in a table

Tags: css, html-table

I have to make a something like a Gantt Diagram. This is what I already accomplish: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=160ecxu&s=6.

For this case I'm working with tables. As you can see in the image I have a gradient in the 1st, 2nd and last rows. I must do it for all the green cells. 
As you can see in the last row although has the gradient the white lines that separte each column disappeared because I made a colspan=11. That's the only way I found to make something similar

Here's some code

HTML

```
    <tr>
       <td class="days selected">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days selected">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       ...
    </tr>
...
...
...
    <tr>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
       ...
       <div class="group">
           <td class="selected" colspan="11"></td>
       </div>
    </tr>
```

and CSS

```
table tr td.selected{
   /*the gradient code here*/
}

/* I TRIED TO SET A STYLE FOR THE GROUP BUT WITHOUT ANY RESULTS*/
table tr div.group{
    background-color:red;   
}
```

Anyone has any tip for keeping the white lines and the gradient?

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` within a `<tr>`

Comment: Hey @paulslater19. When I was researching for a method to accomplish it I found this. http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/#comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I think that was a mistake by Chris, though. If it wasn't (but it is) wouldn't you want to remove your `colspan=11` and have multiple columns?

Comment: @paulslater19: It is indeed a mistake.

Comment: @paulslater19 Yes I can remove the <div> and keeping a colspan and it works the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split the `<td>`'s to eleven single elements and use `background-size` and `background-position` in CSS to make the gradient look like it's spanned over the eleven elements.

**Example Fiddle:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/nfk5t/).

Your HTML code could be like this:

```
<tr>
   <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-1">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-2">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-3">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-4">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-5">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-6">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-7">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-8">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-9">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-10">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="days selected colspan-11 col-11">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Instead of one `<td colspan="11">` you have eleven `<td style="colspan-11 col-n">` elements where `n` is the number of the element.

In your CSS you should make the background gradient size as big as the eleven elements are together. This is `11 * width + 10 * border width`, because you only have ten borders within the area. In this situation my `<td>`'s have a width of 30px and my borders have a width of 2px, so we should make the background `11 * 30px + 10 * 2px = 350px` wide. We can do this with `background-size` in CSS:

```
td.colspan-11 {
    background-size: 350px 1px;
}
```

Then you need to position the background gradient right in each element, to make it appear as one big gradient. For the `n`'th element, we need to move the gradient `n * (width + border width)` to the left. This is done using this code:

```
td.colspan-11.col-1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

td.colspan-11.col-2 {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

td.colspan-11.col-3 {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

/* etc. */
```

See my Fiddle for the full code and a working example.

Comment: can you put a link tou a fiddle exemple?? Thanks

Comment: @user794035 Answer is completed now, including a link.

Comment: thanks. It works nice in ff and chrome. In IE9 didn't work. But thats ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user794035 Good to hear! Did you take a look at the [CSS3 gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) I mentioned in my CSS code in my Fiddle? It has an option to generate an SVG file for support in IE9. Maybe you can get that working?

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think of, which are all ugly:

- overlaying another table on top to get the borders to show
- overlay a div which will have the background, but give it some transparency, so that the borders show
- Split the background up between the cells (or don't have a gradient)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll try them. I'm more optimist to the first one